# How to Load Old Tags into Finder?

Tags: finder, finder-tag

I am using macoOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) and had to reinstall macOS.

The issue is that while the Finder displays the existing tags in the Finder window when viewing all my old files and directory, it doesn't load the old tags for autocompletion when I am tagging a new file. In fact, I have to create a new tag as though the old one doesn't exist.

How can I get Finder to recognize and reuse my old tags?

(I use the "*Edit Tags*" button on the Finder toolbar to edit / assign a tag to a file / directory. Usually it shows the old tags for autocompletion, and in a drop down menu, as you type. But now it only shows recents tags and not the old pre-existing ones.)

Comment: I don't see that behaviour with 10.15.x.  But I suspect that is Not the solution.  I can't test this (as I can't replicate your problem), but have you tried clicking the 'Show All' at the bottom on the tag adding box - that might kick it into seeing all for autocompletion.

Comment: @Gilby Yes, I tried that. But it doesn't show the old tag(s) even though it shows the same tag when viewing a file or folder in Finder. It's just weird. I've even let spotlight reindex the whole drive again (and that was a pain in the ass too).